# for loop and if statement gives wrong argument

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(items=c("^TP53$","^PTEN","^BRACA1$","^SYNE4$","^ATM$"),condition = rnorm(5), 
                  parameter = rnorm(5), id = rnorm(5), reading = rnorm(5))
df1
listid<-gsub('[$|^]',"", df1$items)
protein<-c("PTEN")
fkeep <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(listid)) {
  if (!protein) {discard <- grep(paste0("^", listid[i], "$"), df1$items, fixed = T)}
  else {hits <- grep(paste0("^", listid[i]), df1$items, fixed = T)}
  fkeep <- c(fkeep, hits)
  # print(fkeep)
}
```

I have a data frame df1 and if a name in "listid" it is not in "protein" it get saved to discard , instead if it is in "protein" it is saved to hits and only hits are kept
However I get the following error:

```
Error in !protein : invalid argument type
```

Comment: This seems a very inefficient way to do what you want, if I understand you correctly. At the very least you could replace the loop with `hits <- intersect(listid, protein)` and `discard <- setdiff(listid, protein)`. You might also add to your question the precise output you are hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so there are multiple problems:

```
df1 <- data.frame(items=c("^TP53$","^PTEN","^BRACA1$","^SYNE4$","^ATM$"),condition = rnorm(5), 
                  parameter = rnorm(5), id = rnorm(5), reading = rnorm(5))
df1

listid<-gsub('[$|^]',"", df1$items)

protein<-"PTEN" # this is only 1 item so no c()
fkeep <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(listid)) {
  if (listid[i]!=protein) {discard <- grep(paste0("^", listid[i], "$"), df1$items, fixed = T)} 

# protein is a variable containing only a single argument but you want to choose this argument from listid 
# so you have to loop through listid in search for protein

  else {hits <- grep(paste0("^", listid[i]), df1$items, fixed = T)}
  fkeep <- c(fkeep, hits)
   print(fkeep)
}
```

well after looking at your code again, i found that your grep code isn't working so i took the liberty to rewrite it a bit:

```
for (i in seq_along(listid)){
  if (listid[i]!=protein){
    hits <- sub("^", "", paste0(listid[i], df1$items[i], "$"), fixed=T)
    print(hits)}
    
  #else #{discard<-grep("^", paste0(listid[i], df1$items[i], "$"), fixed=T) # sets protein row to 1
        #{discard<-sub("^", "",paste0(listid[i], df1$items[i]), fixed=T) # changes ^PTEN to PTENPTEN
    #print(discard)}
    
}
```

results now depend on the version of the discard you run

Comment: Error in c(fkeep, hits) : object 'hits' not found

Comment: now it gives  this error, I think the loop is not working

Comment: i edited the answer. the loop was working fine for me although admittedly it only put out numbers and not strings as i assume you would want. your `grep()` command was wrong. i left the original answer so you can compare the commands. if i misunderstood, please provide an example of how you want your results to look like

Comment: I think it is nof what I would like I guess.

Comment: I would like to check if an element of listid is in protein, if it is not, it will grep all the elements which are not in protein from the column data frame an save them in a discard vector (i mean their numbers) so discard = int 1 3 4 5

Comment: if it is in protein again it will grep but in another way the element in the df1 items column and save it as integer in the hits vector so hits = int 2

Comment: it is nice that you put it i a comment, but i suggest updating your question with a line or two of how you would want the result to look like. it seems to me that you only need to separate either proteins or non-proteins because you can always reduce the table to get the "discarded" vector.

Comment: ok I will try to add that

Comment: to be fair, as the question is closed i am not sure you can edit it in a way that is publicly available. if that is the case please show me how your results should look like in the comments. ill edit my answer so you can see the the else statements as comments. you can experiment with them.

Answer (score 2):

Notice how it's telling you there's an error in !Protein.
Including the exclamation mark.

`!` in R is NOT the same as `!=`. `!` can only be applied to boolean vectors. You need  to use a binary operator like `== FALSE` or `!=` instead.

The code is failing because `!` is expecting you to give it a boolean vector. Asides from that, protein also only has 1 element, so there's no reason to use c() on it.